# Running an in-memory function inside a Specflow integration test

Tags: .net, azure-functions

I am currently trying to run an in-memory API and an in-memory function within an integration test using Specflow.

My API runs and starts up fine but I am getting the following error for my function. `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The gRPC channel URI 'http://:65250' could not be parsed.'`

```cs
var _functionsHost = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        // Overriding configuration and using user secrets
    })
    .ConfigureWebJobs((context, builder) => builder.UseWebJobsStartup(typeof(FunctionStartup), new WebJobsBuilderContext
    {
        ApplicationRootPath = context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath,
        Configuration = context.Configuration,
        EnvironmentName = context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName,
    }, NullLoggerFactory.Instance))
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureLogging(l => l.ClearProviders())
    .Build();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing, System.InvalidOperationException: 'The gRPC channel URI 'http://:PORT' could not be parsed.', indicates that the gRPC channel is trying to bind to an invalid URI. The placeholder :PORT suggests that the actual port number isn't being provided or resolved correctly.

Here are a few steps to troubleshoot and potentially resolve the issue:

1. Specify the Port Explicitly:
   Ensure that you're providing a valid port number when setting up your in-memory function. If you're trying to bind to a dynamic port, make sure it's being resolved correctly.

   .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults((workerOptions) =>
   {
   workerOptions.GrpcMaxMessageLength = int.MaxValue;
   workerOptions.FunctionsHostUrl = "http://localhost:YOUR_SPECIFIED_PORT";
   })
2. Logging
   You've cleared providers in your logging configuration. Consider adding some logging providers temporarily to get more detailed logs which might provide more insights into the issue.

   .ConfigureLogging(l =>
   {
   l.ClearProviders();
   l.AddConsole();
   })

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey, sorry I added `PORT` in there in place of the actual number - there is actually a number there. 

I tried to add your code to my builder however it tells me that those two properties are not actually available on that object.

Comment: Azure Functions often rely on environment variables for configuration. Ensure that the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` is set to `dotnet-isolated` and that any other necessary environment variables are correctly set.

Comment: @aaronsalmon as this is being run through a test debugger it is possible that the environment variables are not being set via VS. Do you know a way via config to force the function into `dotnet-isolated` mode via the HostBuilder?

Comment: @Questioning Yes, you can set the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` environment variable directly within your test setup or within the HostBuilder configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately even with the additional code of setting the `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME` it does not work, I still get the same error.